# Using R to find difference between two visits

Tags: r

I have data frame like this

```
vehicleId visitDate taskName
123       1/1/2013  Change Battery
456       1/1/2013  Wiper Blades Changed
123       1/2/2013  Tire Pressure Check
123       1/3/2013  Tire Rotation
456       3/1/2013  Tire Pressure Check
```

I want to do is

```
vehicleId visitDate timeBetweenVisits(hrs)
123        1/1/2013                     24
123        1/2/2013                    672
456        1/1/2013                     48
```

Any thoughts how I can do this using R?

Comment: That is something not valid in my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `res` as in @Dirk's answer, here is a `by` expression that does the job:

```
by(res, res$vehicleId, FUN=function(d)
                       {
                         data.frame(vehicleId=head(d$vehicleId, -1),
                                    visitDate=head(d$visitDate, -1), 
                                    tbv=diff(d$visitDate)) 
                       }
)
## res$vehicleId: 123
##   vehicleId  visitDate    tbv
## 1       123 2013-01-01 1 days
## 2       123 2013-01-02 1 days
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
## res$vehicleId: 456
##   vehicleId  visitDate     tbv
## 1       456 2013-01-01 59 days
```

Comment: hi Mathew, This worked just fine. I m just few days old to R, and just amazed that this can be done with such few lines of code. I have to read a lot about what you did here ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Load and transform the data:

```
## data now comma-separated as you have fields containing whitespace
R> res <- read.csv(text="
vehicleId, visitDate, taskName
123,       1/1/2013,  Change Battery
456,       1/1/2013,  Wiper Blades Changed
123,       1/2/2013,  Tire Pressure Check
123,       1/3/2013,  Tire Rotation
456,       3/1/2013,  Tire Pressure Check", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
R> res$visitDate <- as.Date(res$visitDate, "%m/%d/%Y")     ## now in Daye format
```

Look at it:

```
R> res
  vehicleId  visitDate               taskName
1       123 2013-01-01         Change Battery
2       456 2013-01-01   Wiper Blades Changed
3       123 2013-01-02    Tire Pressure Check
4       123 2013-01-03          Tire Rotation
5       456 2013-03-01    Tire Pressure Check
R>
```

Date calcs:

```
R> res[3,"visitDate"] - res[1,"visitDate"]
Time difference of 1 days
R> as.numeric(res[3,"visitDate"] - res[1,"visitDate"])
[1] 1
R> difftime(res[3,"visitDate"],res[1,"visitDate"], unit="hours")
Time difference of 24 hours
R> as.numeric(difftime(res[3,"visitDate"],res[1,"visitDate"], unit="hours"))
[1] 24
R>
```

Vectorised:

```
R> as.numeric(difftime(res[2:nrow(res),"visitDate"],
+                      res[1:(nrow(res)-1),"visitDate"], unit="hours"))
[1]    0   24   24 1368
R>
```

which you can of course assign to a new column too. You may want to subset by vehicle id as well.

Comment: This is working, But how do i do this for all rows? I am able to sort on vehicleId & visitDate but not sure how would i apply your computation to entire dataset. Its almost 1 million records

Comment: "An Introduction to R" and other documents may be helpful to you here.